# jquery mobile event : after page is fully displayed

Tags: jquery-mobile

developping a web app with JQM, what event can I use instead of `pageshow` to animate a div on a page, after the page is fully displayed, so that the user can see it ?

For now I am using this :

```
$(document).on('pageshow','#welcome-page', function(){


    if (!firstlaunch){
        $('#miniWeightLevel').hide();
    } else {
        $("#userdata").animate({width:'40px', height:'30px'},3000);
        $("#userdata").hide();
        $('#miniWeightLevel').show();
    }
    $('#miniWeightLevel').on('click', function(){   
            $('#miniWeightLevel').hide();
            $('#userdata').removeAttr("style").removeAttr("width").removeAttr("height");
            $("#userdata").show();
        }); 

});
```

but the animation is already done when the page finishes to diplay.

Thanks

Comment: depending on jQM version used, `pagechange` 1.3 `pagecontainertransition` 1.4, but both cant be bound to specific page. Ugly solution is to `setTimeout` 500ms or so.

Comment: Hi, I am using 1.3.2, with pagechange, or pagecontainertransition, the animation doesn't fire at all...

Comment: I know, as I said, `setTimeout()` is the only ugly solution. I'll think of other solutions

Comment: ok thanks @Omar, setTimeout works.

Comment: do you want to write a solution ? or i do it ?

Comment: Do it, it's your call :)

Comment: yeah you're right...maybe the setTimeout() is a bit ugly ;-)

Comment: @Omar, where can I contact you privately ? for a job related matter. Thanks

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/49936/discussion-between-omar-and-louis)